# Updating a combobox from another form vba Excel

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a Userform1 form, inside which there is a combobox called categories, and this field is a list of options that I load into the combobox from a table in excel (using rowsource in the object properties).

From the opened Userform1, if I want to add a new option to the list that appears in the categories field, I put a button that opens a Userform2 where I can create categories. But once I create it and close Userform2 the combobox of Userform1 is not updated. How can I refresh it so that the new option I created from Userform 2 appears?

Thank you very much

Comment: Try `Userform1.Combobox.Requery`.

Comment: Are you setting the rowsource in VBA or in design time?

Comment: Hello, i set rowsource VBA

Comment: I posted a sample. have a look.

Comment: `Combobox.Requery` @Harun24HR is for Access

Answer (score 1):

Set the rowsource at runtime in `UserForm_Initialize()`

**Code in Userform1**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    PopulateCombo
End Sub

Sub PopulateCombo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find Last Row in Col A
        '~~> Change column as applicable
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Identify the range starting from A1
        '~~> Change as applicable
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
        
        '~~> Set your rowsource
        ComboBox1.RowSource = rng.Address(, , , True)
    End With
End Sub
```

And then you can reset the `RowSource` using the `PopulateCombo` code from `Userform2`

Something like

**Code in Userform2**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '
    '~~> After adding data
    '
    
    UserForm1.PopulateCombo
End Sub
```

Comment: Than you very much, I will try

Comment: hello. It didn't work for me. Do you have any other ideas.

Comment: What do you mean it did not work? The code that I have shared above is tried and tested. Can you share your code and error messages if any?